# R splinefun com NA

Tags: r

Alguém já usou o splinefun com uma série de dados com NA?

```
x<-c(0.7948801, 1.3248001, 1.5897601, 8.7436794, 9.5385607, 12.4531202, 13.2480008, 14.0428786, 23.0515214, 23.5814400, 28.3507206, 31.0003216, 31.7951981, 34.7097597, 34.9747231, 37.0944000, 38.4191978, 39.2140825, 40.8038409, 44.5132790, 46.3679953, 52.9920087, 59.0860789, 60.1459215, 60.6758428, 113.9327984, 122.1465702, 142.8134403)

y<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

interpolar <- function(x, y)
{
    f <- splinefun(x, y, method = "hyman", ties=mean)#0.5142539###0.5157599
    qq <- mean(x)
    y_qq <- f(qq)
    N <- length(x)*10
    X1 <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = N)
    res <- list(horiz = y_qq, vert = qq)
    invisible(res)
}

teste<-as.numeric(interpolar(x,y))[1]
    Error in splinefun(x, y, method = "hyman", ties = mean) : 
      zero non-NA points
```

Tudo bem, se ele for NA, que apareça isso como resposta de "teste". A única coisa que eu preciso, é que ele não dê erro e trave o loop inteiro.
(Caso alguém pergunte, não tenho como melhorar o y, o meu dado realmente não existe mesmo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar `tryCatch` para apanhar os erros de execução do código e depois agir de acordo com o resultado. Criei ainda uma função auxiliar, `is.error`, para testar a saída de `splinefun`.

```
is.error <- function(x) inherits(x, "error")

interpolar <- function(x, y){
  f <- tryCatch(splinefun(x, y, method = "hyman", ties=mean),
                error = function(e) e)
  if(is.error(f)){
    res <- f
  }else{
    qq <- mean(x)
    y_qq <- f(qq)
    N <- length(x)*10
    X1 <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = N)
    res <- list(horiz = y_qq, vert = qq)
  }
  invisible(res)
}

teste <- interpolar(x, y)
if(is.error(teste)){
  print(teste$message)
}else{
  teste <- as.numeric(teste)[1]
}
#[1] "zero non-NA points"
```

Uma versão talvez mais simples de utilizar pode ser a seguinte. Neste caso *a função auxiliar não é necessária*. A função `interpolar2` tem um argumento extra, `err.message`, para decidir se a mensagem de erro é ou não printada. Por defeito `err.message = TRUE`. Isto pode ser mudado para `FALSE`, se quiser.

```
interpolar2 <- function(x, y, err.message = TRUE){
  f <- tryCatch(splinefun(x, y, method = "hyman", ties=mean),
                error = function(e) e)
  if(inherits(f, "error")){
    if(err.message) print(f)
    if(grepl("NA", f$message)){
      res <- NA
    }else{
      res <- NULL
    }
  }else{
    qq <- mean(x)
    y_qq <- f(qq)
    N <- length(x)*10
    X1 <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = N)
    res <- list(horiz = y_qq, vert = qq)
  }
  invisible(res)
}

teste2a <- as.numeric(interpolar2(x, y))[1]
#<simpleError in splinefun(x, y, method = "hyman", ties = mean): zero non-NA points>
teste2a
#[1] NA

teste2b <- as.numeric(interpolar2(x, y, FALSE))[1]
teste2b
#[1] NA
```